# Modelate a function based on imputs

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I am making a game( nothing too fancy) and the game is consisting of many levels each with an unique identifier, a number $n\in\mathbb{N};6\leq n \leq 29$. Based on that identifier I need to place an object(a ball) at a specific location on the x axis. So what I did I was trying to create a function $f:\{set\ of\ unique\ id\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. And I was trying to see how my function behaves. i.e.
f(6) = 6.28 ; f(15) = -0.21; f(20) = 1.84; f(25) = 0.02; f(29) = 0.02; But I can't find a general form for my $f$ function. I was trying to construct my function like this $f(x) = c_1 \lg x+c_2 $,and then solve for my $c_1$ and $c_2$ constants but it didn't seem to work. Any ideas?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Maybe what you want to do is interpolation. In order to interpolate your points, you have to decide what kind of interpolation function you want to use.

The easiest approach would be to use polynomials. Let $n$ be the cardinality of the set of unique id's. Use the polynomial $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_ix^i$.

All you have to do is to fill in all pairs $(x, f(x))$, which gives you $n$ equations in $n$ unknowns ($a_0,\ldots,a_{n-1}$). You then solve this system of linear equations by means of linear algebra.

Comment: The interpolating polynomial for that data is $-0.000862562 x^4+0.0708706 x^3-2.03752 x^2+23.0322 x-72.753
$, thanks to [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolate+(6,+6.28),+(5,-0.21),+(20,+1.84)+,+(25,+0.02),+(29,0.02)). The fit isn't great...

Comment: I have tryied to use this polynomial. But for $f(12)$ for example the result is  -145.something which is not the result I expected. By placing the object manually in the scene its x position should be at 2,42.